# I need help how to fix the "else if" = only owner is allowed to call the _action from the main contract. this is just the logger

Tags: solidity

I need help how to fix the "else if" = only owner is allowed to call the _action from the main contract. this is just the logger. below is the contract logger.

contract logger {

```
  function log(address _caller, uint _amount, string memory _action) public {
    if (equal(_action, "withdraw")) {
    revert("It's a frank!");
    
    else if (equal(_caller, "owner"));
    assert();
    }
}

function equal(string memory _a, string memory _b) public pure returns (bool) {
    return keccak256(abi.encode(_a)) == keccak256(abi.encode(_b));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am guessing you want to call the function from the main contract in the logger contract. So we need to know the address of the main contract and the function signature of the `action` function in the main contract. Suppose the function signature of `action` function in the main contract is `action(unit256)`. And let's initialize the main contract in the `constructor`.
So the contract logger would look like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

import "./MainContract.sol";

contract Logger {  
   address private owner;
   MainContract mainContract;
   constructor(address _mainContract){
       owner = msg.sender;
       mainContract = new MainContract(_mainContract);
   }
   function log(address _caller, uint _amount, string memory _action, uint256 value) public {
        if (equal(_action, "withdraw")) {
            // Do whatever you want
        }
        else if (_caller == owner){
            mainContract.action(value);
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }

    function equal(string memory _a, string memory _b) public pure returns (bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(_a)) == keccak256(abi.encode(_b));
    }
}
```

Comment: it got me error it says ParserError: Expected primary expression.
--> BnbBank.sol:49:9:
|
49 | else if (equal(_caller, "owner")) {
| ^^^^

Comment: base on the function below only deposit and withdraw is being monitored. how can i add the "_caller" here?    => function equal(string memory _a, string memory _b) public pure returns (bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(_a)) == keccak256(abi.encode(_b));

Comment: Simply put `_caller == owner` (Sorry I thought `equal` was a custom function)

Comment: To check equality of two strings this will be the syntex:
`if (keccak256(abi.encode(_action)) == keccak256(abi.encode("withdraw"))) {`

Comment: still now working on my side.. could you pls.  drop the whole update on the contract logger to make it work?

Comment: See in the updated answer if this is what you looking for.

Comment: the logger contract has to be deployed first and be added under maincontract constructor target address and be linked.  There are only two functions on maincontract which is deposit and withdraw.  on deposit the logger will do nothing and  on withdraw that's we're the logger will intervene unless the contract owner will call it, then it will assert.  if and else if is my logic. do you think this is possible? i only saw it on youtube.  and wanted to prove if it is possible or not.

Comment: I appreciate all your answers.

Comment: Can you explain what the `assert` is for?

Comment: Use assert() to:

Check for overflow/underflow, ie. c = a+b; assert(c > b)
Check invariants, ie. assert(this.balance >= totalSupply);
Validate state after making changes
Prevent conditions which should never, ever be possible
Generally, you will probably use assert less often
Generally, it will be used towards the end of a function. source: https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e

Comment: what is the proper call to make the msg.sender == owner become Boolean? instead of assert?

Comment: `msg.sender == owner` returns a `boolean` that's why you can use it in an if/else if clause.